# React- How to preserve javascript when rendering server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, pug

I am rendering my react component as so...

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var React = require('react');
var reactDom = require('react-dom/server');
var App = React.createFactory(require('../components/index'));

router.get('/', function(req,res) {
    var reactHtml = reactDom.renderToString(App({}));
    res.render('../../tutorHub/views/index.jade', {reactOutput: reactHtml});
});
module.exports = router;
```

Notice I am using `renderToString`. Now, on my jade file, the component is rendered as so...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
html(lang="en")
    head

        link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="style.css")
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css")
    body
        !{reactOutput}

        script(type="text/javascript", src="../index.js")
```

This renders fine, but none of the even handlers are called. I did some research and it turns out that using `renderToString` does not preserve the javascript in my react component.

How can I render this component server side and still preserve the event handlers?

I am using webpack, do I need to change the webpack.config? If so, how can I do that, my webpack skill are still pretty basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was very simple. In my jade file, I was rendering it as...

```
!{reactOutput}
```

So what I did was change it to...

```
#app != reactOutput
```

and all the event handlers worked

Comment: Those jade operators are really confuse... I read "commented line comparing app with the negative of reactOutput"... Could you explain, Rocky?

Comment: @SparK `#app` in jade is the same as creating an element `<div id="app"></div>`. Now, in my code above, I am passing a variable to jade using node js, the variable is `reactOutput`. The `!=` is simply rendering the variable inside `<div id=`app`></div>` And the `!` simply tells the html to read the variable as pure html, if I used `=` instead of `!=` jade would read the variable in jade syntax instead of pure html